# Looping through data to compare values

Tags: jquery

I have an object with data in the format of:

```
{
    "genres": [{
        "genreId": 1,
        "genre": "Horror",
        "publishers": [{
            "publisher": "Random House",
            "authors": [{
                "author": "Stephen King",
                "publishedYears": [2010, 2011]
            }]
        }, {
            "publisher": "Penguin",
            "authors": [{
                "author": "William Shakespeare",
                "publishedYears": [2004, 2006]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I 'm trying to add data into relevant sections, so from a drop down i can select a Publisher or Author.
So i select Random House and then an author "Jane Smith", i want to add her into the Random house section, so it looks like:

```
    {
        "publisher": "Random House",
        "authors": [{
            "author": "Stephen King",
            "publishedYears": [2013, 2014],
        }, {
            "author": "Jane Smith",
            "publishedYears": [2013],
        }]
    }
```

At the moment i'm doing:

```
$('#addAuthor').on('click', function () {
    var obj = sender.data('obj');
    var publisher = $('#pubdropdown').val();
    var author = $('#authordropdown').val();
    var newObj = [];
    newObj.push({
        'publisher': publisher,
        'authors': [{
            'author': author,
            'publishedYears': []
        }]
    });
})
```

But each time it's just adding another entry so i end up with 2 Random House entries.

So i know i need to go through the 'obj' and check it to see if the publisher exists, if it does just push the author item.  However how can i check the value of obj against newObj when newObj doesnt exist until it's already been pushed?

I've tried something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.genres.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < data.genres[i].publishers.length; j++) {
        if (data.genres[i].publishers[j].publisher == newObj.publisher) {
            //push author only
        } else {
            newObj.push({
                'publisher': publisher,
                'authors': [{
                    'author': author,
                    'publishedYears': []
                }]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant you just check against the publisher variable you are setting inside the newObj? You must know the publisher you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < data.genres.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < data.genres[i].publishers.length; j++) {
        if (data.genres[i].publishers[j].publisher === newObj[0].publisher) {
            data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors.push({
                'author': newObj[0].authors[0].author,
                'publishedYears': []
            });
        } else {
            data.genres[i].publishers.push(newObj[0]);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAmdM/2/) (inspect object in console)